# Unable to get fractional portion of some tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, tuples

I've a text file which contains different information in different lines within tuple. I wish to get the fractional portion within `' '` of each tuple.

The data in the text file look like:

```
('Corredor Sanchez', 'Clara', '663354212','email@something.com')
('Berea Castejon', 'Jorge', '934518811',''email@something.com'')
('Juarez Cruz', 'Veronica', '',''email@something.com'')
```

Expected output I wish to get:

```
Corredor Sanchez, Clara, 663354212, email@something.com
and so on -----
```

I've tried with:

```
with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    for item in f.readlines():
        container = item.strip()
        last_name = container[0]
        print(last_name)
        break
```

I'm getting `(` when I run the script above.

***How can I modify the script to get the output I've shown above?***

Comment: Your text file contains *text*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ast.literal_eval to parse a (valid Python) literal in string form:

```
import ast

with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    for item in f.readlines():
        container = ast.literal_eval(item.strip())
        last_name = container[0]
        print(last_name)
        break
```